# Powershell problem to compare and save it as textfile

Tags: powershell

I have this code to list how many files I have in each subdirectory

```
 dir -recurse |  ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | %{ Write-Host $_.FullName (dir $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count }
```

and it works awesome.
But now I like to save it as a file the result and now I have problem.

I has tried with three different ways but the only thing it does is create the file but there is nothing in it.

I have try with

```
| Export-Csv -Path .\data1.csv -NoTypeInformation
| Out-File -FilePath .\data1.txt
```

and even

```
>> Data.txt
```

Comment: What are you expecting in the final file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `Write-Host`. `Write-Host` displays text but doesn't write it anywhere.

You can use `Write-Output`

```
dir -recurse |  ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | % { Write-Output $_.FullName (dir $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count } | Out-File -FilePath $PSScriptRoot\Log.txt
```

Or you could just skip it:

```
dir -recurse |  ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | % { $_.FullName + ' ' + (dir $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count } | Out-File -FilePath $PSScriptRoot\Log.txt
```

Here's old article about streams: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/

What the article doesn't cover due to its age is the PSv5+ *information stream* (number `6`), to which `Write-Host` now writes - see help topic [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection)